# Can the raku built in accessor methods be overridden by a child class?

Tags: oop, raku

I'm trying to 'override' the built in accessors that raku generates for public $. attributes. However, I could use a bit of help trying to work out why this code fails...

```
class Measure {
    has $.value is rw
}

class Angle is Measure {
    multi method value( $x ) { 
        nextwith( $x % 360 );
    }   
}

my $m = Measure.new( value => 27 );
$m.value = 42;     
say $m;   #Measure.new(value => 42)

my $a = Angle.new( value => 27 );
$a.value = 43; 
say $a;   #Error...

Cannot resolve caller value(Angle:D: ); none of these signatures match:
    (Angle: $x, *%_)
```

Your guidance would be very helpful!

Comment: This question brings renewed attention to [parts of an answer I wrote to another of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59673538/1077672). Read either the whole answer, or focus on the part starting "The above isn't quite right though." and footnote 2. `Angle`'s `value` method is shadowing `Measure`'s but with the wrong signature; it has an argument (`$x`) but accessor methods must have zero arguments. Put it all together and you get the behavior we see here.

Comment: hi @raiph - thank you for the feedback - I guess it's rather non intuitive (for me) that $. accessors do not take an argument so I am condemned to going round the same small circle (well, maybe I'll learn this time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you declare an attribute as being public by using a `.`, Raku will create a method with the same name.

That method takes no arguments.
Even if it is `rw`.
(If you declare the attribute as `is rw` then the generated method is what is actually marked with `is rw`.)

When you use `nextwith` it dispatches to the method in the parent class.

In this case that method takes no arguments.

---

Here is something that at least works:

```raku
class Angle is Measure {
    method value( $x ) { 
        callwith() = $x % 360;
    }   
}

my $a = Angle.new( value => 27 );
#$a.value = 43; 
$a.value(43);
```

Of course that means that `Angle.value` isn't an *lvalue* like `Measure.value` is.
(*lvalue* means that it can be on the left side of `=`.)

So let's do that.

Since we need to do a calculation as part of calling `.value` we need to return a `Proxy`

```raku
class Angle is Measure {
    method value() is rw { 
        Proxy.new:
            FETCH => -> $ { self.Measure::value },
            STORE => -> $, $x {
                self.Measure::value = $x % 360;
            }
    }   
}
```

Note that we can't just use `callsame` or similar in those blocks because they start a new dispatch chain.
Instead we need to call the version of the method in the `Measure` class.

You can use `callsame` or similar if you bind the result of that call to a variable which you use as part of a closure.
(I used `$attr` because it is bound to the actual attribute scalar.)

```raku
class Angle is Measure {
    method value is rw {
        my $attr := callsame();
        Proxy.new:
            FETCH => -> $ { $attr },
            STORE => -> $, $x {
                $attr = $x % 360;
            }
    }
}
```

---

Personally I think that `Measure` should probably be a role, as that makes things easier as you can just access the attribute directly.

```raku
role Measure {
    has $.value is rw
}

class Angle does Measure {
    method value() {
        Proxy.new:
            FETCH => -> $ { $!value },
            STORE => -> $, $x {
                $!value = $x % 360;
            }
    }   
}
```

---

I also have a problem with an angle being declared as just a number without saying it is in Degrees instead of say Radians or Gradians.

Actually you don't even declare it as being a number.

So I might try something like this:

```raku
role Measure {
    has Real $.value is rw;
}

role Angle {…}

class Degrees  {…}
class Radians  {…}
class Gradians {…}

role Angle does Measure {
    method Degrees  ( --> Degrees  ) {…}
    method Radians  ( --> Radians  ) {…}
    method Gradians ( --> Gradians ) {…}
}

class Degrees does Angle {
    method value() {
        Proxy.new:
            FETCH => -> $ { $!value },
            STORE => -> $, $x {
                $!value = $x % 360;
            }
    }
    method Degrees  () { self }
    method Radians  () { !!! } # needs to actually be implemented here
    method Gradians () { !!! }
}
class Radians does Angle {
    method value() {
        Proxy.new:
            FETCH => -> $ { $!value },
            STORE => -> $, $x {
                $!value = $x % τ;
            }
    }
    method Degrees  () { !!! }
    method Radians  () { self }
    method Gradians () { !!! }
}
class Gradians does Angle {
    method value() {
        Proxy.new:
            FETCH => -> $ { $!value },
            STORE => -> $, $x {
                $!value = $x % 400;
            }
    }
    method Degrees  () { !!! }
    method Radians  () { !!! }
    method Gradians () { self }
}
```

Honestly I don't like that either because you are treating a value as a container.

Basically you have it working like this, where you can't have a constant Angle.

```raku
 class Foo {
     has Angle $.bar;
 }

 my $foo = Foo.new( bar => Degrees.new( value => 27 ) );
 $foo.bar.angle = 43;
```

I think that you should require it to work like this, where you can choose whether the Angle is constant.

```raku
 class Foo {
     has Angle $.bar is rw;
 }

 my $foo = Foo.new( bar => Degrees.new( value => 27 ) );
 $foo.bar .= new( value => 43 );
```

Doing it this way would make it so that you can just straight up delete the `value` methods in all of the subclasses, and replace them with a simple `TWEAK`.
(Which is something that you really needed anyway.)
Of course you would also need to remove `is rw` from `$.value`.

I would make it so that you can call `.new` with just a single value rather than `value => 27`.

```raku
role Measure {
    has Real $.value;

    multi method new ( $value ) {
        samewith( :$value )
    }
}

role Angle {…}

class Degrees  {…}
class Radians  {…}
class Gradians {…}

role Angle does Measure {
    method Degrees  ( --> Degrees  ) {…}
    method Radians  ( --> Radians  ) {…}
    method Gradians ( --> Gradians ) {…}
}

class Degrees does Angle {
    submethod TWEAK { $!value %= 360 }
    method Degrees  () { self }
    method Radians  () { !!! } # needs to actually be implemented here
    method Gradians () { !!! }
}
class Radians does Angle {
    submethod TWEAK { $!value %= τ }
    method Degrees  () { !!! }
    method Radians  () { self }
    method Gradians () { !!! }
}
class Gradians does Angle {
    submethod TWEAK { $!value %= 400 }
    method Degrees  () { !!! }
    method Radians  () { !!! }
    method Gradians () { self }
}
```

```raku
 class Foo {
     has Angle $.bar is rw;
 }

 my $foo = Foo.new( bar => Degrees.new( 27 ) );
 $foo.bar = Degrees.new( 43 );
```

There is something that I want you to notice about that last version.
**There is [almost] no code there.**
It is mostly declarative code, which tends to be more noticeable when it is wrong.

(You would need to fill out those parts with `!!!`, but there shouldn't be very much code there.)

---

Anyway my point is that, yes you *can* do that [with `Proxy`], but there is a reason it is more difficult.
You are looking at the problem from a direction that to some extent goes against the design philosophies of Raku.

Comment: Dear Brad - thanks for the comprehensive reply. I am not keen to use the Proxy method since the built in $. accessors are very, very close to my view of the most natural way to consume Units. Angle is a distinctive exception to most units - Length, Mass and so on naturally have Real values. The example I give was golfed to remove the Real type on value to highlight the specific frustration. My design (Physics::Measure) is a little different from yours - but TIMTOADY I guess! https://github.com/p6steve/raku-Physics-Measure